# Single-element set is slower than a bigger set

Tags: python-2.7, list, performance, set

Can anyone help understand why this happens?

The time it takes to covert a `set` to a `list` is, as expected, proportional to its lenght.  Except when its length is 1. Then, it is slower than 2,3, and 4 elements.

To demostrate, running the following in IPython:

```
for i in range(1, 7):
   s = set(range(i))
   print('%s elements:' % i)
   %timeit list(s)

1 elements:
1000000 loops, best of 3: 187 ns per loop
2 elements:
10000000 loops, best of 3: 170 ns per loop
3 elements:
10000000 loops, best of 3: 174 ns per loop
4 elements:
10000000 loops, best of 3: 179 ns per loop
5 elements:
10000000 loops, best of 3: 182 ns per loop
6 elements:
1000000 loops, best of 3: 202 ns per loop
```

I'm using python2.7.